# undefined object for map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, react-hooks

I am learning react. I just want to test double binding for an array with hooks, so I create a table with and input that modifies the property of the object that I set in the state. After setting the state, I am getting a  Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

I compare original object and the new object and both have the same structure

```
//For App.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Person from './Person/Person'
import './App.css';

const App = props => {

  const [peopleState, setPeopleState] = useState({
    people: [{ id: "001", name: "John Smith", address: "Main AV", phone: "312312" },
    { id: "002", name: "Marc Muller", address: "Second AV", phone: "345435" },
    { id: "003", name: "Sam Lopez", address: "Thrid AV", phone: "456444" },
    { id: "004", name: "Peter McNiece", address: "Road AV", phone: "213456" }]
  });

  const changeHandler = (event, index) => {
    //This should be changed by using a copy
    console.log(JSON.stringify(peopleState))
    const newList = peopleState;
    const newObj = peopleState.people[index];
    newObj.name = event.target.value;
    newList.people[index] = newObj;
    setPeopleState({ newList })
    console.log(JSON.stringify(peopleState))
  }

  let listOfPeople = null;
  listOfPeople = (
    <div>
      {
        peopleState.people.map((p, index) => {
        return <Person name={p.name} address={p.address} phone={p.phone}
          changed={(event) => changeHandler(event, index)} />

      })}
    </div>)

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Example</h1>
      {listOfPeople}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

//For Person.js
import React from 'react';
import './Person.css';

const person = (props)=>{
    return(
        <div className="Person">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>{props.name}</td>
                    <td>{props.address}</td>
                    <td>{props.phone}</td>
                    <td><input type="text" onChange={props.changed} value={props.name} /></td>
                </tr>    
            </table>    
        </div>
    );
}

export default person;
```

By the way, do I have to clone the objects of the state if I am doing updates?

Comment: Hi James, just wrote an answer for you below. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish the appearance of double-binding like this

Also here is the sandbox if you want to see it in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/7345kyly21

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Person from "./Person";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const App = props => {
  const [peopleState, setPeopleState] = useState({
    people: [
      { id: "001", name: "John Smith", address: "Main AV", phone: "312312" },
      { id: "002", name: "Marc Muller", address: "Second AV", phone: "345435" },
      { id: "003", name: "Sam Lopez", address: "Thrid AV", phone: "456444" },
      { id: "004", name: "Peter McNiece", address: "Road AV", phone: "213456" }
    ]
  });

  const changeHandler = (event, index) => {
    const newList = peopleState.people.map((person, pIndex, array) => {
      if (index === pIndex) {
        return {
          ...person,
          name: event.target.value
        };
      } else {
        return person;
      }
    });

    setPeopleState({ people: newList });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(peopleState);
  }, [peopleState]);


  const renderList = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        {peopleState.people.map((p, index) => {
          return (
            <Person
              name={p.name}
              address={p.address}
              phone={p.phone}
              changed={event => changeHandler(event, index)}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Example</h1>
      {renderList()}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Also on the same note, the reason why you are getting undefined map error is because of this:

```
setPeopleState({ newList })
```

When you pass in arguments like this, you are passing in a new key-value. Your state variable becomes { newList: [arrayofpeople]} and you still try to map over peopleState.people in render. Where `.people` is no longer a key in your state, which is why you are getting undefined.